# Was 'life' inherently/objectively good in Nietzsche's philosophy? How to overcome Nihilism?

Tags: ethics, nietzsche, good-and-evil

I understand that after Nietzsche got rid of objective morality in his philosophical process, he went ahead and claimed that even though there is no objective morality that his personal philosophy deems that one has to live life and was kind of an advocate for stoicism and even brought forth the idea of the Ubermensch and so his personal philosophy was to do 'good' to others and be kind as long as it guarantees one's life or improvement of it.

But my question is, isn't he subscribing to the idea that 'life' is good and therefore inherently accepting the idea that some things are inherently good.

I mean, I agree, one cannot necessarily say or logically argue that death is 'good' in the nihilist sense and therefore believe this and go forth to attain it.

Comment: See e.g. Robin Small, [Friedrich Nietzsche: Reconciling Knowledge and Life (Springer 2016)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Friedrich_Nietzsche/GD2FCwAAQBAJ) and Bernard Reginster, [The Affirmation of Life: Nietzsche on Overcoming Nihilism (Harvard University Press, 2006)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Affirmation_of_Life/SBWVmMF_rqUC)

Comment: And what if he was?

Comment: @ScottRowe doesn't that mean in one way or another Nietzsche, did find some meaning after all i.e., life. He found that life or existence is good, ultimately good.

Comment: And then, suddenly...

Comment: @ScottRowe I am trying to say that after all Nietzsche's process is not consistent and doesn't hold because by the end of the day He deemed life, 'existence' to be objectively good.

Comment: Yes, it is very frustrating when people are not consistent. I don't know, does he actually *say* that he thinks life is objectively good? He would probably say it if he really thought so. Would it be better to be correct in saying that life is bad, or wrongly just go ahead and like it?

Comment: @ScottRowe I see what you mean, fair point